# How do I get the other side of the border to print?

Tags: c, extended-ascii

I have a c program that uses extended ascii to print out a box based on two params you enter, one is width, the other is height.

Currently I can get my box to look like:

```
╔══════════╗
║
║
║
║
║
║
║
║
╚══════════╝
```

But I cannot figure out how to do the right side of the box border. What I have is below:

**box_ascii.h**

```
#ifndef __box_ascii_h__
#define __box_ascii_h__

// Might not be exact Extended Ascii Characters but they come from:
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode

#define BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER         "\u2554" // ╔
#define BOX_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER        "\u2557" // ╗
#define BOX_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER      "\u255A" // ╚
#define BOX_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER     "\u255D" // ╝
#define BOX_SIDE                    "\u2551" // ║
#define BOX_TOP_BOTTOM              "\u2550" // ═

#endif
```

**create_dynamic_box.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "box_ascii.h"

void print_border(int width, int height);
void print_top_border(int row, int col, int width, int height);
void print_left_side_border(int row, int width);
void print_bottom_border(int row, int col, int width, int height);

// Main App.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("Mustenter width and height.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Print the actual border.
    print_border(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]));

    return 0;
}

// We want to print the actual box border.
void print_border(int width, int height) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    print_top_border(row, col, width, height);
    print_left_side_border(row, width);
    print_bottom_border(row, col, width, height);
}

// This is the top part of the border.
void print_top_border(int row, int col, int width, int height) {
    for(row = 0; row < width; row ++) {
        for(col = 0; col < height; col++) {
            if(row == 0 && col == 0) {
                printf("%s", BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER);
            }

            if(row == 0 && col < height) {
                printf("%s", BOX_TOP_BOTTOM);
            }

            if(row == 0 && col == height - 1) {
                printf("%s\n", BOX_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Print the left side of the border.
void print_left_side_border(int row, int width) {
    for(row = 0; row < width; row ++) {
        if(row < width -2) {
            printf("%s\n", BOX_SIDE);
        }
    }
}

// This is the bottom part of the border.
void print_bottom_border(int row, int col, int width, int height) {
    for(row = 0; row < width; row ++) {
        for(col = 0; col < height; col++) {
            if(row == width - 1 && col == 0) {
                printf("%s", BOX_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER);
            }

            if(row == width - 1 && col < height) {
                printf("%s", BOX_TOP_BOTTOM);
            }

            if(row == width - 1 && col == height - 1) {
                printf("%s\n", BOX_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have everything written but the `print_right_side_border` which I thought would be the same as the `print_left_side_border` but I was wrong. Everything I do has the right side border print under the bottom border.

My goal is to eventually allow you pass in a third param to allow you to say create top, bottom, right but not left. Hence why I am trying to do each border piece as a function.

**Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: Hint: you will have to print both sides at the same time.

Comment: A pedantic note, but there is no such thing as "Extended ASCII", except in as much as there are many different 8-bit character sets which use ASCII for their first half. Since what you're echoing are actually Unicode code points, the term is competely irrelevant here.

Comment: You cannot print "at" a position in plain C, you *must* print the spaces in between as well. To print 'at', either use OS dependent functions (old Turbo C's `gotoxy` comes to mind) or look up on `ncurses`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should handle both sides (left and right) simultaneously...
Print the left border, fill with spaces until you reach the right border and print that as well.

Should you need to omit either one of the two borders, you just print spaces instead of the ASCII characters you chose..

I believe you could follow the same approach for the top - bottom borders as well, but in that case it also works just fine as you have done it